# SAML2 Toolkit SSO integration (java)

Tags: web-applications, glassfish, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

Hello I am currently searching for a solution to integrate a SAML2 based SSO into my java web application which is running on a glassfish server. My application is splitted into a front and a backend and they communicate via a wsdl interface. I am currently using the [SAML Toolkit](https://github.com/SAML-Toolkits/java-saml/tree/master). I used the provided example and I integrated the functionality to redirect the user to the IdP where he can enter his credentials and gets again redirected to my login page with an assertion response that the login was successful. But my user assertion needs to be done in the backend and I cannot simply forward the response because then the security of my app is compromised is'nt it? Is it somehow possible to get an kerberos token from my IdP which I can then forward to my backend, which will then reauthenticate it? Or can I send the login-response from the IdP directly to the SP, but how does then the browser know about it? Or is there another approach, how can I achieve a secure SAML SSO functionality with my design?

I am searching for a solution for quite a while now and was not able to achieve anything great. Can someone guide me into a certain direction?

Comment: you could change your ACS URL in your SAML metadata to be a backend URL and the SAML Response from the IdP will go there instead of the front end.

Comment: @codebrane Thank you for your reply! That seems to be a good idea, but doesn't the user gets redirected to the login-page with no information about the login then? The backend then knows it, but how does then the webclient learn about it, so I can connect them?

Comment: I've added a possible solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to change the Assertion Consumer Service (ACS) URL in the SAML metadata to be a backend URL e.g.

```
https://backend.yourapp.com/acs
```

The user goes to the front end, e.g.

```
https://frontend.yourapp.com/
```

which sees they are not authenticated (perhaps no backend session for them at this point). So the front end redirects them to the IdP where they login. It could use a backend service to do that. That would keep all SAML information and processing in the backend.

The IdP then redirects them to the ACS URL in the backend. The ACS backend service validates their SAML attributes from the IdP and if appropriate, it creates an authenticated session for them in the backend and then redirects them to the front end, e.g.

```
https://frontend.yourapp.com/user/profile/
```

So when they finally reach the profile URL above, the backend has validated their SAML attributes and logged them in to the system based on those attributes. The session will have an expiry time based on how long the SAML attributes are valid for.